# Is "/" equal to "window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host"

Tags: javascript, ajax

When doing AJAX request in JavaScript, is there any case where it could be necessary to write

```
window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host
```

instead of simply

```
/
```

After all, files like images, scripts, and css are always specified relative so it should be the same when making ajax requests.

The reason I'm asking this is because I can't find any official suggestion (e.g. from w3c) on how to do it.

Comment: If they mean the same thing, I wouldn't expect to see any official suggestions of one over the other, at least nothing regarding correctness.

Comment: where does it say the mean the same thing. My question is based on assumptions, and they worked so far :P

Comment: As you know, window.location.protocol is the protocol currently in use, window.location.host is the host currently in use, finally / will take you back to the root of your web container, which should already start with the current protocol and host. It's context paths you want to be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not strictly the same, as `window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host` is missing the trailing slash to indicate the root directory. But for all intents and purposes, they can be used interchangeably.

In practical usage, assuming you're not using `<base>`, all of the following will point to the same place:

```
window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/'
window.location.href
'//' + window.location.host + '/'  //useful if you don't know the scheme and don't want to check
'/'
```

`window.location.host` contains the port number if it's anything other than 80, so you shouldn't have to worry about including that. It's simpler and clearer to write `'/'`, as it always means "the root directory of whichever server this page came from." Things could get hairy if the URI contains something like `username:password@` -- I don't know of a way to get that data using JS. Trying to reassemble a URI from individual components could cause problems if the code is migrated to an unusual environment like that.

The formal definition for all of this is in [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which is not exactly light reading.

Answer (score 1):

I can only come up with one difference: If you have a `<base />` Tag in your HTML document, AJAX (at least jQuery does) seems to consider this tag and change your URL.

In any other case, the two should behave the same. And you should avoid `<base>` anyway.

```
<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <base href="http://example.com/foo/" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>$.get("/bar");</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#">Base test</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they mean exactly the same, but to be honest, I'd suggest just using `/`. Simply because it's a raw string instead of `Object->Object->string + string + Object->Object->script` if that makes sense.